# Processing a stack of images in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am currently working on an image processing task that requires me to process a stack of .png images all at once in Matlab (I have very limited matlab knowledge). I have looked at various sites trying to figure out how to do this. My most recent attempt was based on the answer in this link: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7665-images-to-stacks, however I keep getting the error:
    "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts"
My .png's are numbered sequentially (Heart 001.png, Heart 002.png,...) and my exact code is as follows:

```
I = zeros(240,320,253,'uint8');
for ii = 1:253
    I(:,:,ii) = imread(sprintf('Heart %s.png'),num2str(ii,'%03i')));
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to be downloading imshow3D.m from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41334-imshow3d--3d-imshow- ,
and then implementing the following code:

```
clear;
clc;

I = zeros(240,320,253,'uint8');
for k = 1:253
    PNGFileName = strcat('Heart ',32, num2str(k), '.png');
    imageData = imread(sprintf(PNGFileName));
    Heart = imageData(:,:,1);
    I(:,:,k) = Heart;

end
imshow3D(I)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your image reading code looks fine, but the way you construct the file names is wrong. You are passing the result of `num2str` to `imread` as it's image format argument, but you intended to pass it to `sprintf`. How about you try `imread(sprintf('Heart %03d.png', ii));`?

Comment: Sorry, the last comment was incomplete. I meant to say:             Another method that I have been trying is:                            for k = 1:253
                                                                  PNGFileName = strcat('Heart ',32, num2str(k), '.png');
                                                               imageData = imread(sprintf(PNGFileName));
                                                        imshow(imageData)
                                                                  end
Which runs without an error however only shows the last slice of the stack.

Comment: Several points: (a) `strcat('Heart ',32, num2str(k), '.png');` would not give you the series of file names you describe in your original question, it would instead include two spaces between Heart and the number, and the number would not be zero-padded. (b) MATLAB only updates figures at the end of execution, thus you see only the last image. To force a figure update, use `drawnow` or `pause`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I actually have my heart files saved both ways (zero padded and not zero padded) so when running this particular script I make sure to have the current folder open to the heart files that are (Heart 1.png, Heart 2.png,...) I forgot to say that in my comment. Anyway, when using the `drawnow` command I can now see the figure changing as each individual slice overwrites the last, however in the end the figure is still just the last slice.